# DialogFragment lifecycle strange behavior on rotation

Tags: java, android

I'm a newbie in Android development, so i'm stuck with an DialogFragment lifecycle behavior.All i want my DialogFragment to do is represent authentication dialog with login and password TextViews and two buttons. It seems that it creating itself twice. I'm trying to log the lifecycle, so it works like:

```
onAttach 
onCreate 
onCreateDialog 
onCreateView
onActivityCreated 
onViewStateRestored
onStart 
onResume 
onSaveInstanceState
onDetach 
onAttach 
onCreateDialog 
onCreateView
onActivityCreated 
onViewStateRestored
onAttach 
onCreate 
onCreateDialog 
onCreateView
onActivityCreated 
onViewStateRestored
onStart 
onStart 
onResume 
onResume 
onDetach 
onSaveInstanceState
onDetach 
onAttach 
onCreateDialog 
onCreateView
onActivityCreated 
onViewStateRestored
onAttach 1
onCreate 
onCreateDialog 
onCreateView
onActivityCreated 
onViewStateRestored
onStart 
onStart 
onResume 
onResume 
onDetach
```

The problem is when i'm trying to rotate device savedInstanceState is set to null, because when it's not null onAttach and others methods being called. Here is my DialogFragment code:

```
public class SignInDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

private SignInDialogListener mSignInDialogListener;


private EditText mUsername;
private EditText mPassword;
private Button mReset;
private Button mLogin;
private Integer count=0;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_sign_in, container);


    Log.v("test","onCreateView");


    this.getDialog().setTitle(R.string.login);

    mUsername = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
    mPassword = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.password);
    mReset = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.reset_button);
    mLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    setRetainInstance(true);//helps to avoid Dialog creates many times on rotation

    mReset.setOnClickListener(this);
    mLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

public void onAttach(Activity context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    count++;
    Log.v("test","onAttach "+count);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try {
        // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
        mSignInDialogListener = (SignInDialogListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement AuthenticationDialogListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("login",mUsername.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("password",mPassword.getText().toString());
    Log.v("test","onSaveInstanceState");

}


@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v("test","onViewStateRestored");



}



@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("test","onCreateDialog ");
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
}

public static SignInDialog newInstance() {
    return new SignInDialog();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.equals(mLogin)) {
        if (mPassword.getText().toString().length() < 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.invalid_password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else {
            mSignInDialogListener.onSignInDialogLoginClicked(mUsername.getText().toString(),
                    mPassword.getText().toString());
            this.dismiss();
        }
    } else if (v.equals(mReset)) {
        mSignInDialogListener.onSignInDialogResetClicked(mUsername.getText().toString());
    }
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("test","onActivityCreated ");
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    Log.v("test","onStart ");
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v("test","onCreate ");
    super.onResume();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.v("test","onResume ");
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    Log.v("test","onDetach ");
    super.onDetach();
}
```

And the code from activity where i'm creating DialogFragment

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeActivity(savedInstanceState);
    }


    private void initializeActivity(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mSignInDialog = new SignInDialog();
        mSignInDialog.setCancelable(false);//to avoid back button pressed
        mSignInDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Login");



        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        mSearchRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.search_recycler_view);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.search_progress_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mSearchViewPresenter = new SearchViewPresenter(MainActivity.this);

    }
```

Comment: Obviously you should not create another SignInDialog instance when `savedInstanceState != null` and fragment exists in FragmentManager this is well explained in basic fragment documentation

Answer (score 0):

As explain in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) :

> Some device configurations can change during runtime (such as **screen orientation**, keyboard availability, and language). When such a change occurs, **Android restarts the running Activity** (onDestroy() is called, followed by onCreate()).

So when you rotate the screen, the whole procedure to destroy the activity is processed and then it is re-created. Your fragment being attach to an activty follow the same process.

For your savedInstance problem you can follow the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#saras) about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can can check your fragment has already attached to current fragment manager. If it already added before you can dismiss current fragment.

```
        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);

            Fragment loginFragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Login");
            if(loginFragment != null){
                dismiss();
            }
        }
```

I assumed you started dialog at activity